# Joomla login with form

Tags: php, joomla, authentication

We are trying to make a login form to login in joomla with an external php script.
When i add my joomla credentials manually the login works. But when i add a form it keep saying that no user is found.

Can someone help us ?

This is the code of joomla1.php (the joomla login script)

```
<?php
/**
 * Joomla! External authentication script
 *
 * @author vdespa
 * Version 1.0
 *
 * Code adapted from /index.php
 *
 * @package    Joomla.Site
 *
 * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.1', '<'))
{
die('Your host needs to use PHP 5.3.1 or higher to run this version of Joomla!');
}

/**
 * Constant that is checked in included files to prevent direct access.
 * define() is used in the installation folder rather than "const" to not error for PHP 5.2 and lower
 */
define('_JEXEC', 1);

if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/defines.php'))
{
include_once __DIR__ . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

// Instantiate the application.
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

// JFactory
require_once (JPATH_BASE .'/libraries/joomla/factory.php');

// login credentials from login.php
$credentials['username'] = $_POST["user"];
$credentials['password'] = $_POST["passw"];

/**
 * Code adapted from plugins/authentication/joomla/joomla.php
 *
 * @package     Joomla.Plugin
 * @subpackage  Authentication.joomla
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

// Get a database object
$db    = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
->select('id, password')
->from('#__users')
->where('username=' . $db->quote($credentials['username']));

$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadObject();

if ($result)
{
$match = JUserHelper::verifyPassword($credentials['password'], $result->password, $result->id);

if ($match === true)
{
    // Bring this in line with the rest of the system
    $user = JUser::getInstance($result->id);
    echo 'Joomla! Authentication was successful!';
}
else
{
    // Invalid password
    // Prmitive error handling
    die('Invalid password');
}
} else {
// Invalid user
// Prmitive error handling
die('Cound not find user in the database');
echo $_POST["user"];
}


?>
```

This is the code of the form (login.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left">Show Popup Form</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" class="ui-content" style="min-width:250px;">
  <form method="post" action="joomla1.php">
    <div>
      <h3>Login information</h3>
      <label for="usrnm" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm" placeholder="Username">
      <label for="pswd" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="passw" id="pswd" placeholder="Password">
      <label for="log">Keep me logged in</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="login" id="log" value="1" data-mini="true">
      <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Log in">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>

<div data-role="footer">
<h1>Footer Text</h1>
</div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Depending on your end goal, I suspect you might be doing way more work then required.  To clarify, are you trying to override the authentication source, template styling or both with this customization?

Comment: Hi. I have an external php script and i want my visitors to login with their credentials of the joomla installation on my server to identificate themselves. But lightweight for mobile use so therefor the custom login form.

Comment: Since you are authenticating against the Joomla DB, unless there is a functional purpose I'm missing, there isn't a need for the joomla1.php script (which in current form is open to a SQL Injection Attack).  Are end users navigating to the main website URL to access this dedicated mobile log in?